# How can I write my listener function somewhere else if it uses local variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I am a beginner in Javascript development and I have to do the classical to-do app. It has to be object-oriented and my program has two classes: Task and Tag. 
A task contains some tags.

When the user clicks on a tag, he can modify its name. First, I did wrote an anonymous callback function which was listening to the modification form submission and it worked well. But, I have to create a named function declared somewhere else instead of my existing listener. However, I need to access to some of the properties of my object (which is edited) and I have absolutely no idea how to do a thing like that.

Here is a small part of my code:

```
  module.Tag = class Tag {
      constructor(name = 'untitled', parent = null) {
          this.name = name;
          this.parentTask = parent;
      }

      //Method which displays the tag name
      display_name() {
        return $('<li>').addClass('tag').text(this.name);      
      }

      //Method which displays the tag
      display() {
        let tag_item = this.display_name();

        let field = $('<input>').prop('type', 'text').prop('value', this.name);
        let button = $('<button>').addClass('validationButton').prop('type', 'submit').text('✓');
        let removeButton = $('<button>').addClass('removeButton').text('X');
        let form = $('<form>').append(field).append(button).append(removeButton);
        let in_edit = false;

        tag_item.click((event) => {
          event.stopPropagation();
          event.preventDefault();

          let target = $(event.target);

          if (target.is('li') && !in_edit) {
            tag_item.empty();
            tag_item.append(form);
            in_edit = true;          
          }

          if (target.is('button') && target.prop('type') === 'submit') {
            if(field.val() !== '') {
              this.name = field.val(); 
              module.StorageManager.storeTasks();
            }

            tag_item.empty();
            tag_item.text(this.name);

            field.val(this.name);

            in_edit = false;
          }

          if (target.is('button') && target.hasClass('removeButton')) {
            if(confirm('Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer ce tag ?')) {
              tag_item.remove();
              this.removeTagFromParent();

              module.StorageManager.storeTasks();  
            }
          }
       });

       return tag_item;
     }

     //Method which removes the tag from the parent task
     removeTagFromParent() {
       this.parentTask.removeTag(this);
     }
  };
```

My listener is in the display method and it uses `Tag.name` property and some of the variables created in the method body. I can't see how to write this function somewhere else and Google didn't help me.

I hope my problem is clear, English is not my native language.
Some advices?

Comment: "*I have to create a named function declared somewhere else instead of my existing listener*" - why? Use the code that works.

Comment: Use a closure .

Comment: I would if my professor didn't ask me to do a specific function somewhere else. The other reason is that I have the same listener in another part of my code and I could avoid duplicate code if I find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Despite my reflexion, I can't find how a closure could help me here. As I said, I'm a beginner and many obvious practices aren't natural for me yet.

Comment: Keep the existing function expression for the listener, but not its body. Replace everything inside the function by a call to the named function, and pass any parameters and local variables that you need as arguments to it.

Comment: It seems so obvious now. It's a shame I didn't think about it. Thank you, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract your anonymouse function to be another class method.  It is an event handler so in order to correctly access the defined object you'll have to bind it correctly.

Here is an example of the modified script:

```
module.Tag = class Tag {
      constructor(name = 'untitled', parent = null) {
          this.name = name;
          this.parentTask = parent;
      }

      //Method which displays the tag name
      display_name() {
        return $('<li>').addClass('tag').text(this.name);      
      }

      //Method which displays the tag
      display() {
        let tag_item = this.display_name();

        let field = $('<input>').prop('type', 'text').prop('value', this.name);
        let button = $('<button>').addClass('validationButton').prop('type', 'submit').text('✓');
        let removeButton = $('<button>').addClass('removeButton').text('X');
        let form = $('<form>').append(field).append(button).append(removeButton);
        let in_edit = false;

        tag_item.click(this.handleClick.bind(this));  
        // this is where you invoke the function and 
        //bind it to the context of the class

       return tag_item;
     }

     //Method which removes the tag from the parent task
     removeTagFromParent() {
       this.parentTask.removeTag(this);
     }

     // extracted method defined here:
      handleClick(event) {
          let tag_item = this.display_name();
          let field = $('').prop('type', 'text').prop('value', this.name);
          event.stopPropagation();
          event.preventDefault();

          let target = $(event.target);

          if (target.is('li') && !in_edit) {
            tag_item.empty();
            tag_item.append(form);
            in_edit = true;          
          }

          if (target.is('button') && target.prop('type') === 'submit') {
            if(field.val() !== '') {
              this.name = field.val(); 
              module.StorageManager.storeTasks();
            }

            tag_item.empty();
            tag_item.text(this.name);

            field.val(this.name);

            in_edit = false;
          }

          if (target.is('button') && target.hasClass('removeButton')) {
            if(confirm('Voulez-vous vraiment supprimer ce tag ?')) {
              tag_item.remove();
              this.removeTagFromParent();

              module.StorageManager.storeTasks();  
            }
          }
       }
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Another problem is that I have to write the function outside of my Tag class so I can't access to 'this.name' or 'this.display_name()'.

Comment: To have the function outside of the class, you would extract the name function body 'handclick' outside of it.  You'd then have to modify the function to accept argument(s) to either handle the scope of the Tag item class OR direct arguments to accept the value for tag_item and field.

Comment: Glad I could help :-)